# Why am I getting 20 in the output?

Tags: c

why am I getting 20 in the output as auto variables have block scope?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a=0;
    {
         int a=10;
         printf("%d",a);
         a++;
         {
             a=20;
         }
         {
             printf(" %d",a);
             int a=30; {a++;}
             printf(" %d",a++);
         }
         printf(" %d",a++);
    }
    printf(" %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10 20 31 20 0
```

Comment: Variables *declared* in a block have block scope; an *assignment* to a variable is permanent though - it's not like assignments are rolled back once you get out of that block. If you replace `a = 20;` in the inner block with `int a = 20;` you will get the output you're expecting.

Comment: Read this. Youll understand why [http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Scope](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Scope)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking why `printf(" %d",a);` (note leading space) prints `20` even though `int a=30;` appears in the same block scope (though *after*) as the aforementioned `printf`) ?

Answer (score 1):

The `a=20;` statement is within its own block scope, however `a` was not defined in that scope, therefore it looks for a definition of `a` in the next outermost scope.  Here, it finds `a` that was initialized to 10, and sets it to 20.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare a new variable in the inner block, you simply referred to the variable that was declared earlier. If you change your code to:

## include

```
int main(void) {
    int a=0;
    {
         int a=10;
         printf("%d",a);
         a++;
         {
             int a=20;
         }
         {
             printf(" %d",a);
             int a=30; {a++;}
             printf(" %d",a++);
         }
         printf(" %d",a++);
    }
    printf(" %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Then you'll get the output you expect. `int a = 20` is a declaration, `a = 20` is just an assignment.